# Replace the /system/lib/libstagefright.so in Android and can't boot

Tags: android, frameworks, media, android-source, stagefright

I complied the libstagefright using the Android 2.3.3_r1 source code and generated the libstagefright.so file. Then I replaced the /system/lib/libstagefright.so in my phone(HTC g14 android 2.3.x) with it.  But my phone can't reboot after that(stuck in the booting screen).

I have done the same work in HTC g8 before. In some ROMs, it's ok without any problems. And in others, I have the same problems. So anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way (maybe the only way) is to boot in fastboot mode (power + volume down) and flash a new ROM on your phone.

The fastboot mode may vary, so if it doesn't work you need to search how to enter fastboot mode for your device (google it!).

You will also need to search a compatible ROM for your phone (google it again!).

---

There are a bunch of reasons why this happened, it is not as easy as you think to just change a lib. When you build the source code, everything is extremely tied up! It is not just about this specific lib, all the other libs that depend on this one might crash if it is not exactly what they are expecting.

Example:

1. It's almost the same as getting the libstagefright.so from another device (Nexus One) and try to put on your phone
2. If you try to flash this code you compiled on your phone, will it work? Answer: No!

---

Solution:

If you want to play with stagefright, first you need to find and build the source code (search on xda-developers) for your specific device. If you build it, flash it and the devices boots up without any problems, then you can play with libstagefright.so without many problems!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I really want to know the reason why the phone can't start after replacing some system libraries. It's available in some ROMs, but not all. And I have used the same version of Android source code and given the root user the rw authority.